# Typescript search field name to match with column name

Tags: mysql, typescript, express

Hi I am creating an api to let admin to search user in database with different field.

```
// Restrict user to search these fields only
type SearchFieldType = 'name' | 'memberNo' | 'email' | 'companyName';

const dbCol = ['username','member_no','email','company_name'] as const;
```

When admin pass the parameters in api, they can either pass one search field or multiple to search the data.

How could I detect which field is passed in the api and search the relative column in database.

Not using if else because column might increase in future.

Thanks in advanve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a corresponding SearchFieldType for each db column. You can do it in such maner so that when adding a new dbCol will result in error in the mapping.
Example:

```js
type SearchFieldType = 'name' | 'memberNo' | 'email' | 'companyName';

type DbCol = 'username'|'member_no'|'email' |'company_name';

const colToSearchTimeMapping: Record<DbCol, SearchFieldType> = {
    email: "name",
    username: "memberNo",
    member_no: "memberNo",
    company_name: "companyName",
}
```

[typescprit playground with added column that results in error](https://tsplay.dev/mMLKkN)